# How to show associated data in add form in cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-3.0

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE `user_roles` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `role_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=39 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `users` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `username` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `user_role_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I created the insertion and deletion for user roles . No i have to add the users with user roles. In the user adding form user role is displaying as empty. here is my code:
**UserTable.php:**
            namespace App\Model\Table;

```
            use Cake\ORM\Table;
        use Cake\Validation\Validator;

        class UsersTable extends Table
        {
            public function initialize(array $config)
           {
              $this->hasMany('UserRoles', [
                    'foreignKey' => 'id',
                    'sort' => ['UserRoles.role_name', 'ASC']
                ]);
                $this->displayField('role_name');
        }   }

        UserController.php

        public function add()
        {
            $this->set('title', 'Add Users');
            $users = $this->Users->newEntity();
            if($this->request->is('post')):
                $users = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request- 
                 >data);
                if($this->Users->save($user)):
                    $this->Flash->success(__('User was created 
                     successfully.'));
                    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
                endif;
            endif;
            $this->set('users', $this->users);
            $this->set('user_roles', $this->Users->UserRoles->find('list', 
             ['id', 'role_name']));
        }
            **add.ctp**
        <?php 
        //print_r($user_roles);
        echo $this->Form->create($users, ['class' => 'form']);
            echo $this->Form->input('username');
        echo $this->Form->input('email');
        echo $this->Form->input('user_role_id');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
        echo $this->Form->button(__("<i class='fa fa-save'></i> Save"));
        echo $this->Form->end();
        ?>
        **UserRolesTable.php**
        namespace App\Model\Table;

        use Cake\ORM\Table;
        use Cake\Validation\Validator;

        class UserRolesTable extends Table
        {
        public function initialize(array $config)
        {
        $this->belongsToMany('Users', [
                'foreignKey' => 'user_role_id'
            ]);
        }

        public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
        {
        $validator->notEmpty('role_name', 'Role name cannot be empty.');
        return $validator;
        }}
```

Its showing empty select box for user_role_id. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to camelCase the View variable for the options for the magic to happen, so it should be `$userRoles` rather than `$user_roles`:-

```
$this->set('userRoles', $this->Users->UserRoles->find('list', ['id', 'role_name']));
```

Cake will then know to associate the variable with the form field. Otherwise you will have to specify the variable used for the options as suggested by Jun.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add options to your input in your view :

```
echo $this->Form->input('user_role_id', ['options' => $user_roles]);
```

instead of

```
echo $this->Form->input('user_role_id');
```

Comment: The other answer from drmonkeyninja is the recommended solution.